# What is the default handler for the child logger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

I understand that the root logger has the `lastResort` handler that prints to the console if the root logger handler is not configured using `logging.basicConfig` and the user makes use of the `logging.info/debug/warning/error/critical("some msg")`
Or `logger = logging.gerLogger()` followed by `logger.info/debug/warning/error/critical("some msg")`

But for a child logger created using `logger = logging.getLogger("someName")`, when we write `logger.info/debug/warning/error/critical("some msg")`, and there is no handler configured, and when `propagate = true`, then does the child logger have any default handler? Or does it fall back to ancestor's handler, and then to root logger's handler and if ancestors/root logger have no handler then to the root logger `lastResort` handler?

If propagate was set to false, then would there be some default handler assigned to child logger?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: [logging.lastResort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort)

Long answer:

According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#what-happens-if-no-configuration-is-provided)，if no logging configuration is provided, then:

> The event is output using a ‘handler of last resort’, stored in logging.lastResort. This internal handler is not associated with any logger, and acts like a StreamHandler which writes the event description message to the current value of sys.stderr (therefore respecting any redirections which may be in effect). No formatting is done on the message - just the bare event description message is printed. The handler’s level is set to WARNING, so all events at this and greater severities will be output.

Also according to the [logging source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b0eb046cbd0dbb7b17f16aad6de20fac5305f387/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1654-L1657):

```py
class Logger(Filterer):
    # ...
    def callHandlers(self, record):
        # ...
        # found is the number of handlers
        if (found == 0):
            if lastResort:
                if record.levelno >= lastResort.level:
                    lastResort.handle(record)
```

So if there is no handlers, it will call `lastResort`, whatever it's a root logger or child logger. `lastResort` is actually [`_StderrHandler(WARNING)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b0eb046cbd0dbb7b17f16aad6de20fac5305f387/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1190-L1204), and this is:

```py
class _StderrHandler(StreamHandler):
    """
    This class is like a StreamHandler using sys.stderr, but always uses
    whatever sys.stderr is currently set to rather than the value of
    sys.stderr at handler construction time.
    """
    def __init__(self, level=NOTSET):
        """
        Initialize the handler.
        """
        Handler.__init__(self, level)

    @property
    def stream(self):
        return sys.stderr
```

So you can see that it's actually a **StreamHandler with WARNING level**.